# Como alterar a cor do plano de fundo do popup menu do app

Tags: android, popup

Gostaria de saber como eu altero a cor do plano de fundo de quando eu abro o menu de um aplicativo que estou criando.

Segue o `style.xml`

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Como eu faço pra alterar essa cor?

Comment: Por favor, especifique a pergunta e a linguagem.

Comment: estou criando um aplicativo android.    e nesse aplicativo ira conter alguns menus...   eu quero alterar a cor do plano de fundo do  popup ... esse "popup" é  aquela janela que abre quando vc aciona o menu para escolher um item   do menu ..  esse style.xml  é um arquivo do android studio que acredito ser o local certo para alterar a cor que desejo  .. porem   não sei como  e exatamente isso que eu quero aprender..

Comment: Faco um tema e coloque as cores que deseja.
Faca o download do tema e subtitua em seu app.
Coloque as imagens nas pastas nao se esqueca disso. https://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso você deve alterar o `AppTheme.PopupOverlay`

Segue um exemplo:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: exatamente isso   muito obrigado!!!!!

Comment: voce por um acaso sabe como alterar a cor de quando o mouse passa por cima .....  tipo fica mais claro   ?

Comment: Mouse? Não sei se é possível!